# Is there an issue of symbols clashing in my particular code?

Tags: ruby, symbols, ruby-2.0, name-clash

The following code works, though I worry that it's by chance.

The `:admin` in `factory :admin` is not intended to refer to the `:admin` in my second statement (`User::ROLES.index(:admin)`).

**test/factories/factories.rb**

```
factory :admin, parent: :user do
  role_type User::ROLES.index(:admin)
end
```

Again, it works, though I still wonder if I should make this adjustment just to be safe:

```
factory :admin_user, parent: :user do
...
```

Comment: `:admin` is like `11`, it doesn't refer to anything but itself and its meaning depends on the context.

Answer (score 1):

Your first code is correct. `:admin` is a Ruby symbol that doesn't by itself point to anything. As the commenter says, it's like using the number `3` in multiple places.

That said, someone reading that code later may be confused by seeing `:admin` twice in two lines of code with different meanings. So to improve readability, I would make the change.